# Handling google sign in alert buttons

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-signin

How do I handle google sign in buttons?

say I have this this button;

[image]

and after the person hits sign in,

it pops up this with confetti pod in the background running.

[image]

Though, if a user hits cancel, the confetti keeps running.

So, how do i handle the google buttons to make the confetti stop?
+ Take the user to another story board if they're fully signed in?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @YuryImashev currently, UIKit GoogleSignIn SAConfettiView

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/ I suppose that it user clicks `Cancel` the `signIn` method should return an error, something like `cancelledByUser`.